# Estimate default by importance sampling (using R)

Tags: r, monte-carlo, importance-sampling

I want to use Importance sampling to estimate probability of  default of an insurance company within the next  $t$ years. The company starts with  capital $C$ at $t=0$. Each year it gains $p > 0$ in premiums and losses  $X \sim F$  independently of other years:

$$Z_t = C + tp - \sum_{i=1}^{t} X_i$$

probability of default can be written as:

$$P(min_{\lt t \leq T}Z_t < 0) =  E(1(min_{\lt t \leq T}Z_t < 0) )$$

Implemeting this in R , by letting x be a vector of simulated  yearly losses. The function returns True if the company defaulted

```
default <- function(x,C,p){
  T <- length(x)
  Z_t<- C + p*seq(1,T,by=1) - cumsum(x)
  return(min(Z_t) < 0)

}
```

Let the loss distribution be independent $LogNormal(0,1/4)$. Simulating from this distribution and then taking the average However it is ineffeicient since the default probability very small ( less than  $0.1\%$). When $t=20$ years, $C=15$ and $p=1$.

The idea is to instead sample from  $Y_i \sim LogNormal(\mu,1/4)$. For some suitable choice of $\mu$.To make the default probability higher.

Using Importance sampling:
$E(h(X))  =  \int h(x)f_X(x)dx =\int h(x)f(x)\frac{f_Y(x)}{f_Y(x)}dx = E\Big(\frac{h(Y)f_X(Y)}{f_Y(Y)}\Big)$

we can take the expectation of: 
$$1(min_{\lt t \leq T}Z_t < 0) \frac{f_X(Y)}{f_Y(Y)}  $$

The ratio of two lognormal densities $\frac{f_X(Y)}{f_Y(Y)}$ with $X \sim LogNormal(0,1/4), Y \sim LogNormal(\mu,1/4)$ with $\mu$ and the data as a parameters can be implemented as

```
w <- function(Y,mu){
  exp(-log(Y)^2/0.5)/exp(-((log(Y)-mu)^2)/0.5) 
}
```

Suppose now that we want to estimate Probability of default in the upcomming $t=20$ years with Starting capital $C=15$ and with premium $p=1$.

We run 10000 simulations with $\mu=0.5$ and finally average

```
N <- 10000
mu <- 0.5
hw1<-replicate(N, 
           {y <- exp(rnorm(20,mean=mu,sd=1/2))
           default(y,C=15,p=1)*w(y,mu)}
)
mean(hw1)

[1] 0.6254667
```

62% which is way too large. I cant see where this went wrong. Can someone give me some advice?

Answer (score 1):

In the code

```
       y <- exp(rnorm(20,mean=mu,sd=1/2))
       default(y,C=15,p=1)*w(y,mu)
```

'y' is a vector of dimension 20. However,

```
w <- function(Y,mu){
     exp(-log(Y)^2/0.5)/exp(-((log(Y)-mu)^2)/0.5)}
```

returns a vector as well since the entry `Y` is vector of dimension 20. It should be a product

```
w <- function(Y,mu){
     prod(exp(-(log(Y)^2-(log(Y)-mu)^2)/0.5))}
```

or equivalently

```
w <- function(Y,mu){
     exp(sum((log(Y)-mu)^2-log(Y)^2))/0.5)}
```

With this modification, the outcome is quite small

```
  > mean(hw1)
  [1] 0.000450381
```

as expected. And also highly variable as repeated calls to the code demonstrate.